# How do I fix 'npm ERR! Test Fail' or get a verbose readout on the error so I can figure out how to resolve it?

Tags: command-line-interface, npm-install

I just completed a global install of nodemon, then I installed mocha dependencies but when I run 'npm test' in a separate tab, the test loads but fails completely and I receive the error message: 'npm ERR! Test Failed. See above for more details'.

I read through the text above the error message but it's just the failed test run. Meanwhile the first tab reads: [nodemon] starting `node server/index.js` so I don't understand the error issue. I tried to get clarification using 'man npm' but didn't have any success.

Is there a solution or a way to get more info on the npm error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the second half of my question, which was how to get a more verbose readout on the npm test error so I can figure out how to resolve it.

Type: **npm test node-name** 
In my case the node was nodemon.

When I just typed '**npm test**' I didn't get much of an explanation on why the test failed. But when I added the name of the node I was testing it resulted in a detailed response on the error that I couldn't understand on my own. With the help of my instructor, we worked it out from there.

I'll leave the question posted in case it can help someone else or in case I forget and need to circle back to my own question!